# how can I get ad image/video from facebook ad

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [Facebook ads library API](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=political_and_issue_ads&country=BD&media_type=all)
I can get `id`, and `page_id` and there is another option to preview add `ad_snapshot_url`, this API does not provide add media(image/video)

is there any alternative option to retrieve media using this `id` and `page_id`

**sample API**: *ads_archive?ad_reached_countries=NL&search_terms=''&fields=id,ad_snapshot_url,page_name,page_id*
**Sample Response**:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "1074678253022683",
      "ad_snapshot_url": "https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=1074678253022683&access_token=EAAIh.......GC2akJ",
      "page_name": "European Commission",
      "page_id": "107898832590939"
    },
    {
      "id": "332252448116343",
      "ad_snapshot_url": "https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=332252448116343&access_token=EAAIh.......GC2akJ",
      "page_name": "European Commission",
      "page_id": "107898832590939"
    },
    {
      "id": "711700709521195",
      "ad_snapshot_url": "https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=711700709521195&access_token=EAAIh.......GC2akJ",
      "page_name": "European Commission",
      "page_id": "107898832590939"
    },
    {
      "id": "363024648586062",
      "ad_snapshot_url": "https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=363024648586062&access_token=EAAIh.......GC2akJ",
      "page_name": "World Vision Nederland",
      "page_id": "349312760804"
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you already get the idea to show the ad_snapshot_url image? If yes can you please let me know

Comment: Sorry, I could not find it

Comment: I Research and find that fb does not allow that use independently

Comment: Yes, I got that, But I am wondering that many ad spy sites show images, even original ad URL.